# IntervalTree query from database?

Tags: algorithm

Just to be clear, when I say IntervalTree I'm referring to this data structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

I want to build a query-able representation of the RIPE database. I want to, given an IP, retrieve its RIPE record. How do I do this?

I have a prototype of this in the following way. Use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intervaltree, parse the RIPE file, encode IP strings like '123.123.123.123' into integers, use this to build an intervaltree using the above-mentioned module.

The problem is that this structure is too large to hold in memory. Is there some database that would be appropriate to use which has native support for something like an interval tree?

Answer (score 0):

Your need is covered by an R-Tree index.  They are more general than you'd think you want because they are designed to handle multiple dimensions.  But you can implement them in one dimension, and they will allow for efficient range searches.

Lots of databases have them, but will call them different things.  For example MySQL calls it a SPATIAL index, while PostgreSQL implements them as a type of GiST index.

Comment: Not sure I understand completely. I would expect that what you described would work on MySQL exactly like a binary tree (i.e. a simple DB index) but instead of BTREE it's an R-tree. However, from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html it doesn't seem to work the same, in the sense that a BTREE index is something that you add on top of any column which can have any data type you want, whereas this R-Tree thing requires the column to be of a special data type called `GEOMETRY`. What am I missing?

Comment: could you please clarify how to use this geometry data type? I was trying to use `POINT` but from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-mysql-specific-functions.html#function_point it seems like `POINT`s are always 2 dimensional. To implement a look-up on IPs i would expect to have something that is one-dimensional.

Comment: @oneloop See https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/using-mysql-spatial-extensions-for-range-queries/